# How to display a KeyValueGroupedDataset in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I am trying to learn datasets in Spark. One thing I can't figure out is how to display a `KeyValueGroupedDataset`, as `show` doesn't work for it. Also, what is the equivalent of a `map` for `KeyValuGroupedDataSet`? I will appreciate if someone give some examples.

Comment: can you show a reproducible example? SO is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, I got the idea from examples given [here](https://sumitpal.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/some-data-gymnastics-with-spark-2-0s-datasets-and-equivalent-code-in-rdds/) and [here](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-two-part-2/). I am giving below a simple example that I've written.

```
val x = Seq(("a", 36), ("b", 33), ("c", 40), ("a", 38), ("c", 39)).toDS
x: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Int)] = [_1: string, _2: int]

val g = x.groupByKey(_._1)
g: org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[String,(String, Int)] = ...

val z = g.mapGroups{case(k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x._2).toArray)}
z: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Array[Int])] = [_1: string, _2: array<int>]

z.show
+---+--------+
| _1|      _2|
+---+--------+
|  c|[40, 39]|
|  b|    [33]|
|  a|[36, 38]|
+---+--------+
```