# How to group tuple dataset by one of its elements in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I read parquet file into dataset of Tuples:

```
val dataset = spark.read.parquet("some-path").as[Tuple2[KeyClass, ValueClass]](Encoders.kryo)
```

I can see it with:

```
import spark.implicits._
dataset.map(x => s"$x._1 : $x._2").show(false)
```

```
+----------------------------+
|value                       |
+----------------------------+
|(1, 2)                      |
|(1, 3)                      |
|(2, 3)                      |
+----------------------------+
```

My KeyClass and ValueCLass are actually complex class with other nested classes (I can't post excect classes and result of show method here, because code is proprietory, but below are their structure):

KeyClass:

```
public class KeyClass implements WritableComparable<KeyClass> {
    private byte[] field2;
    private byte[] field3;

    ...

    public boolean equals(Object o) {...}
    public int hashCode() {...}
}
```

ValueClass:

```
public class ValueClass implements Writable {
    private OtherClass1 field1;
    private OtherClass2 field2;
    private boolean field3;
    private Long field4;
}
```

I need to group it by one of the elements of the tuple:

```
+----------------------------+
|value                       |
+----------------------------+
|(1, [2, 3])                 |
|(2, 3)                      |
+----------------------------+
```

I've tried:

```
val value1 = dataset.groupByKey(_._1)(Encoders.kryo)
val value2 = value1.mapValues(_._2)(Encoders.bean(classOf[ValueClass]))
val value3 = value2.mapGroups({case (key, value) => (key, value.toList)})
```

or

```
value1.mapGroups((a, b) => (a, b.map(_._2))).show(false)
```

I receive exception on the following exception on the line with mapGroups method:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving object InterfaceAudience
```

I've also tried to add other encoders to that method:

```
 val value3 = value2.mapGroups((a, b) => (a, b.toArray))(Encoders.tuple(Encoders.bean(classOf[KeyClass]), Encoders.bean(classOf[Array[ValueClass]])))
```

And after that I see different exception on the same method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to read it into a dataframe and use dataframe transformations/groupBy?

Comment: Also, would you mind trying out showing what is the result for each step? So do this -> val value1 = dataset.groupByKey(_._1)(Encoders.kryo) and then value1.show(false)    because I don't think it is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: @GamingFelix I thought about it overnight, I will try to read into dataframe.
Answering your second comment, I can't do value1.show because dataset.groupByKey operation returns KeyValueGroupedDataset and it doesn't have show method
I've tried the following: value1.mapGroups((a,b) => (a,b)).map(x => s"$x").show(false)
But it gives the same mistake as in my question.
Seems that (a,b) => (a,b) this causes it, but i don't yet know how to workaround this

Comment: Here's an example on how to show it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918836/how-to-display-a-keyvaluegroupeddataset-in-spark    but yeah I would recommend DataFrame if you can. It has a lot of good examples online

Comment: I can't (or at least I have troubles with it) read it as dataframe, because my tuple actually consists of complex classes with other nested classes

Comment: @GamingFelix Suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918836/how-to-display-a-keyvaluegroupeddataset-in-spark - g.mapGroups{case(k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x._2).toArray)} gives the same exception:(

Comment: You can still use Dataframe for that. You can define your own datatype or use something called struct. Also I realize it would probably help you a lot to show what your ValueClass and KeyClass actually is. It doesn't look like complex nested classes to me, as I can only see you have a tuple of two ints.

Comment: Also, please add additional code an examples that you try. Are you saying you tried val value1 = dataset.groupByKey(_._1)(Encoders.kryo)    and then val value2 = value1.mapGroups{case(k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x._2).toArray)    and lastly value2.show   ??? If so, can you add that to your code and write what your get for exception and so on. I might not be able to help you, but the more you add, the higher chance someone else might be able to help

Comment: I added structure of my classes to the description and also the reason why I can't post the exact classes
I also commented my other attempts to resolve my problem.
Anyway, thank you @GamingFelix

Comment: Yeah sorry I can't help further than that. I don't quite understand what is going on with your encoders and so on. I'd recommend looking into using dataframes for it instead or at least split it up as much as possible. Hope someone else can help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy was done correctly, the problem was in usage of Encoders.
My custom classes were imported from legacy code of another project, and they doesn't have correct encoders for them and also doesn't adhere to rules to create bean encoders for them. So I just needed to explicitly specify correct encoder for every operation:

```
dataset
  .groupByKey(_._1)(Encoders.kryo)
  .mapGroups((a,b) => (a, b.map(_._2).toList))(Encoders.kryo)
```

Please point out if my explanation about encoders is somehow vague or incorrect.